# How to write the following snippet in a correct Scala functional way?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm very new to Scala and wanted to know if this is the correct way of writing:

```
def createCol(prior: List[Int], current: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if (prior.isEmpty) List(1) ++ current
  else if (prior.tail.isEmpty)   // begin of the block to improve
    createCol(prior.tail, current ++ List(prior.head))
  else
    createCol(prior.tail, current ++ List(prior.head + prior.tail.head))
}
```

The part I'm interested in is this:

```
if (prior.tail.isEmpty)
  createCol(prior.tail, current ++ List(prior.head))
else
  createCol(prior.tail, current ++ List(prior.head + prior.tail.head))
```

As I'm repeating almost the same function call `createCol` so I tried this instead:

```
val ssum = if (prior.tail.isEmpty) prior.head else prior.head + prior.tail.head
createCol(prior.tail, current ++ List(ssum))
```

What's the best or recommended way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few points:

1. I changed your function to use Scala's pattern-matching framework since it greatly simplifies your code.
2. You shouldn't do `List(x) ++ someList` because this constructs a single-item list unnecessarily.  You should just use the prepend method `::` (or `+:`).  Same goes for appending (`:+`).
3. If `prior` only has one element, you know that all the recursive call is going to do is prepend `1` to the front of `current`.  So you can drop the recursive call from the second case.
4. Your method is tail-recursive, so annotate it with `@tailrec`.
5. Finally, consider using a `Vector` instead of `List`.  Appending to a `List` is O(n) because the method must traverse all the way to the end (and then reconstruct the List from the back to the front). But both prepending and appending to a `Vector` are effectively O(1).

So:

```
@tailrec
def createCol(prior: List[Int], current: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  prior match {
    case Nil => 1 :: current
    case head :: Nil => 1 +: current :+ head
    case head :: tail => createCol(tail, current :+ (head + tail.head))
  }
}
```

You could also do it in two cases, like you described in your question.  But you should use the `headOption` method instead of explicitly doing an `if/else`:

```
@tailrec
def createCol(prior: List[Int], current: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  prior match {
    case Nil =>
      1 :: current
    case head :: tail =>
      createCol(tail, current ++ List(head + tail.headOption.getOrElse(0)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function seems to be equivalent to the following:

```
def createCol(prior: List[Int], current: List[Int]) =
  if (prior.isEmpty) 1 :: current
  else 1 :: current ::: (prior, prior.tail :+ 0).zipped.map(_ + _)
```

Or with `Vector` which should yield better performance for prepend and append if the lists are long:

```
def createCol(prior: Vector[Int], current: Vector[Int]) =
  if (prior.isEmpty) 1 +: current
  else (1 +: current) ++ (prior, prior.tail :+ 0).zipped.map(_ + _)
```

That avoids recursion and I think it's clearer to see that `current` is not modified, that `1` is just prepended regardless and that prior is summed with itself with an offset of 1 with the last element by itself (summed with `0`) and then appended to current.

Or even to avoid the repetition of (1 +: current):

```
(1 +: current) ++ (
  if (prior.isEmpty) Vector()
  else (prior, prior.tail :+ 0).zipped.map(_ + _))
```